# How to hide LoginActivity when app is starting?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have a LoginActivity that leads to MainActivity once the authentification has been made.
In this LoginA, I also have a "RememberMe" checkbox. If the user checks it, he doesn't have to fulfill the authentification form and doesn't even have to click on the Log In button anymore.

Is there a way if the checkbox is checked to not display the LoginA but to start my app with the MainActivity?

In my manifest, I have this:

```
<activity
     android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Using persistent Storage you can achieve. If user selects the checkbox, then keep a flag in database or Shared Preference and use that flag at the start of the app to check whether user had selected checkbox or not. I am also assuming you are saving login response somewhere.

Comment: @ShadowDroid Yes it would be a good solution. But it doesn't tell me how programmatically I can let my manifest knows that MainA should be visible first and not LoginA

Comment: Either you introduce a `SplashActivity`(basically screen which shows your app log or app branding) to be visible first in it  you can have redirecting logic based on flag to Login or MainActivity. **OR** you can have fragment for splash screen and login screen in LoginActivity initially show splash screen then based on flag either load login screen or redirect to MainActivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new activity known as splash screen which will navigate to login screen or your main activity. You can save a boolean value in shared preference for authentication instsance. If authentication is true then navigate to main activity else go to login activity. The splash screen should be your launcher activity.

Comment: I've barely heard of SplashScreen. So I'm gonna give it a go. Thank you very much for your explanation!

Comment: @Lena Splashscreen is a simple activity for the authentication logic and also to display your application logo and app version(optional).